# Not able to retract sharepoint solution using SPTool.Library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using SPTool.Library and trying to retract a globally deployed wsp but it is giving me the following error:
Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

Code:
SPTReturn returnObj = farm.RetractSolution(wspName);

When I try to retract a wsp that is deployed to a web application then it retracts it with no problems. Can this be an issue related to globally deployed solution or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message it appears that the `RetractSolution` method expects the *solution ID* instead of the solution name. It is a [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) formatted as the message suggests. You can get solutions deployed to your farm incuding their IDs by the PowerShell cmdlet [`Get-SPSolutions`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607754.aspx), for example.